# Google cloud storage: The caller does not have permission

Tags: java, rotation, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts

I am trying to rotate key to access GCS bucket using service account and API. I have enabled  all roles to my service accounts but still i am getting error as follows.

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpTransport transport;
        try {
            transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        Iam iam = new Iam(transport,jsonFactory,new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
                httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(0);
                httpRequest.setReadTimeout(0);
            }
        });

        CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest createServiceAccountKeyRequest = new CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest();

        Create create = iam.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().create("projects/mysampleproject/serviceAccounts/myserviceaccount@newsampleproject-123465.iam.gserviceaccount.com", createServiceAccountKeyRequest);
        create.setKey("AIzaSyC_YlBg_UXEFgdsspbGLvyb-THrTCbbZA");
        ServiceAccountKey serviceAccountKey =create.execute();
        System.out.println(serviceAccountKey.getPrivateKeyData());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried from my same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064306/how-can-i-key-rotate-for-google-cloud-storage-service-account). Please can anyone suggest me where i am wrong or how to achieve it in right way?

Comment: Which account are you using to run this code, your own or a service account? Does that account have permission to create service account keys? The permission's name is iam.serviceAccountKeys.create.

Comment: Service account key which you are using is not valid or it could be from another project.

Comment: The `403` you get in your question, is this in response to your request to create a service account or in response to a follow up request **using** the service account you've obtain with the code above?  If the former, does the account used to request a new service have the [`iam.serviceAccountKeys.create`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create) permission as suggested by Brandon?  Lastly, your previous comment is missing some context and seems to be an error message.  Are you getting this message when trying to create a service account or use one?

Comment: I think it is not possible to run the code from main method. Here HttpRequestInitializer object wont have authorization data. Try like Iam iam = new Iam(transport, jsonFactory, credential); Where credential is OAuth credential.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648929/authenticate-service-account-without-downloaded-key-on-google-app-engine/43718783#43718783

Answer (score 0):

"mysampleproject" needs to match "newsampleproject-123465" in "newsampleproject-123465.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

Also it's worth to try using Google Application Default Credentials

```
     HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();    
     JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

     // Authenticate using Google Application Default Credentials.
     GoogleCredential c= GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

     Iam iam = new Iam(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential);
```